# Flask not resolving bootstrap glyphicons?

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, glyphicons

[image]

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app. I'm currently trying to add a datepicker to a page. I've found https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/. This cookiecutter uses flask-assets to manage the project assets.

I installed it via bower but deleted the bootstrap components in bower because I already have bootstrap in my static files. When I run my profile page I see the datetimepicker displayed, but with missing components:

```
 <div class="form-group">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
                inline: true,
                sideBySide: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I look in the console I see:

[image]

But in the top screenshot the files seem to be present. What am I doing wrong?

edit:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /users/profile HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /static/libs/font-awesome4/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /static/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/spacelab/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /static/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /static/css/home.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /static/libs/jQuery/dist/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /static/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /static/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /static/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /static/js/plugins.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /_debug_toolbar/static/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /_debug_toolbar/static/js/jquery.tablesorter.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:12] "GET /_debug_toolbar/static/js/toolbar.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:13] "GET /_debug_toolbar/static/css/toolbar.css?0.2746632904869951 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:14] "GET /static/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:14] "GET /_debug_toolbar/static/img/tick.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:14] "GET /static/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:14] "GET /static/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2016 11:22:14] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Does the code have a hard time finding the bootstrap.css file too? Can you see the path that has?

Comment: as you make the call from the template ??? Your call path is wrong. you're working from localhost?

Comment: comment @user61629

Comment: That is what I was getting at... I think your path is wrong... look at the boostrap.css path in the Net tab and see where it gets that.

Comment: I've added the requests for the page /users/profile , above.As  far as I can tell everything else resolves normally.

Comment: Thanks , I finally understood what you meant, the path was wrong , see below

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Flask not resolving assets. Setting good permissions on your static files will allow Flask to read it.

```
chmod 644 /static/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.*
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the thought but actually I realized that for whatever reason flask was looking for the glyphicons in the wrong place. I copied the fonts folder to under css and it started working correctly.